# Quill Mention throws TypeError s.domNode.getBoundingClientRect is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-fullstack, react-quill

Trying to mention users with @ character in the quill editor throws TypeError s.domNode.getBoundingClientRect is not a function in the console and the suggestions are not shown.

Steps for Reproduction
The error is a little tricky to reproduce as only a few of my company's clients occasionally experience the issue on production.
screenshot below

[Pleasee see screen shot for issue here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/elAdc.jpg)

Expected behavior:
The mention feature should show the suggestions

Actual behavior:
The following error is thrown in the console and the suggestions don't work

TypeError
s.domNode.getBoundingClientRect is not a function
Platforms:

browser: Chrome 104.0.5112.101 (Official Build) (arm64)
device: Mac
os: Mac OS X 11.4 (BigSur)

Comment: Please share a piece of code where you actually initialising the Quill editor.

Answer (score 1):

Here is in example of initialising the Quill.
Please make sure that you have `bounds: document.body` line included.

```
const quill = new Quill('#editor', {
    modules: {
        toolbar: [
            [{ header: [1, 2, false] }],
            ['bold', 'italic', 'underline'],
            ['image', 'code-block']
        ]
    },
    bounds: document.body,
    placeholder: 'Compose an epic...',
    theme: 'bubble' // or 'bubble'
});
```